# Constants of integration for a linear system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the system of linear differential equations

\begin{align}
x'(t) = \frac{x(t)}{t} - y(t) \tag1\\
y'(t) = \frac{y(t)}{t} + x(t) \tag2
\end{align}

for $t>0$.

An elegant method to solve this system is to multiply $(2)$ by the imaginary unit $i$ and adding that to $(1)$ to obtain

\begin{align}
x'(t) + iy'(t) = \frac{x(t) + iy(t)}{t}+ix(t)-y(t) = \frac{x(t) + iy(t)}{t}+i(x(t)+iy(t)) \tag3
\end{align}

Letting $z(t):=x(t)+iy(t)$, $(3)$ becomes

\begin{align}
z'(t) = \left(\frac{1}{t}+i\right)z(t) \tag4
\end{align}

which is a seperable equation that can easily be solved. This gives us

\begin{align}
z(t)=Cte^{it} \tag5
\end{align}

where $C$ is an arbitrary constant.

From there, $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ arise as the real and imaginary part of $z(t)$.

> What I'm having trouble with are the constants of integration. As this is a system of two first-order differential equations, shouldn't there be two constants of integration, one for each equation? What happened to the second one?

Comment: $C$ is a complex number $C_1+iC_2$, which contains two constants.

Comment: Of course! Thanks a lot. In hindsight, it's obvious. Then $x(t)=t(C_1\cos t - C_2\sin t)$ and $y(t) = t(C_1\sin t + C_2\cos t)$, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. :)